# Gradle building Spring Boot library without Main Class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, jar

I am trying to build a Spring Boot/Gradle project and create a jar without a main class. My purpose is that this project is a library that will be pulled in by other projects therefore the library project does not require a main class to run. Unfortunately, no matter what kind of gradle config I write I keep getting errors when I try to `build install` about not having a main class or not being able to find the `bootJar` task.

Here's what my gradle file looks like:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.7.RELEASE' apply false
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'maven'

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    enabled = true
}

bootJar.dependsOn fooTask
```

But when I run this I get the following error:

> Could not get unknown property 'bootJar' for root project
>   'foo-library' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

What in my configuration needs to change?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Disable **bootJar** in your `build.gradle`

```
bootJar {
   enabled = false
}
```

Comment: But this prevents the creation of a jar which I need so I can pull it into another project

Comment: nope this doesn't create however who creates the jar is this task `jar {  enabled = true } `

Comment: I get the error: `Could not find method bootJar() for arguments [build_7m5kgf5tb8ptc46mos1k0piwt$_run_closure23@29435193] on root project 'foo-library' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`

Comment: are you building from your parent `build.gradle`? right? if it is, then you need to add `bootJar { mainClassName = 'NONE' }` in parent build.gradle.

Comment: tasks.bootJar { enabled = false }

Answer (score 1):

In my case by using `gradle kotlin dsl`:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile
import org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.bundling.BootJar

tasks.getByName<BootJar>("bootJar") {
    enabled = false
}

tasks.getByName<Jar>("jar") {
    enabled = true
}
```

Solved the issue.

source:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10238#issuecomment-544227301